# Как запомнить рандом в боте?

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram. Нужно, чтобы бот выводил рандомное число, а потом в следующем сообщении с остальным текстом вывел это же число.
Через присваивание переменной не вариант, потому что тогда у других пользователей бота рандомное число будет одинаковым

Comment: Только в базе хранить для каждого chat_id свое

Comment: в любом хранилище: в базе, в memcache, redis...да хоть в файлике если хотите. Что удовлетворяет вашим требованиям - то и используйте. Главное, чтобы каждому пользователю сохраняли его сгенерированное число.